# Encapsular valores retornados por JSON dentro de um único objeto

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou com uma dúvida, tenho este código abaixo no `controller`:

```
[Authorize]
    public JsonResult Teste()
    {

        var licencas = new List<Object>();
        licencas.Add(new {
                            Responsavel = "José",
                            Ticket = 79007,
                            Descricao = "RC - 01 Desktop padrão - José",
                            Status = "Pendente Gestão",
                            SLA = "10/10/2013"
                        });
        licencas.Add(new {
                            Responsavel = "Maria",
                            Ticket = 79037,
                            Descricao = "RC - 01 Notebook padrão - Maria",
                            Status = "Pendente Pedido",
                            SLA = "10/11/2013"
                        });            

        return this.Json(licencas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Que retorna o seguinte JSON:

```
[
   {
    "Responsavel":"José",
    "Ticket":79007,"Descricao":"RC - 01 Desktop padrão - José",
    "Status":"Pendente Gestão",
    "SLA":"10/10/2013"
    },
    {"Responsavel":"Maria",
     "Ticket":79037,
     "Descricao":"RC - 01 Notebook padrão - Maria",
     "Status":"Pendente Pedido",
     "SLA":"10/11/2013"
   }
 ]
```

Mas eu preciso que retorne assim:

```
licencas = [
   {
    "Responsavel":"José",
    "Ticket":79007,"Descricao":"RC - 01 Desktop padrão - José",
    "Status":"Pendente Gestão",
    "SLA":"10/10/2013"
    },
    {"Responsavel":"Maria",
     "Ticket":79037,
     "Descricao":"RC - 01 Notebook padrão - Maria",
     "Status":"Pendente Pedido",
     "SLA":"10/11/2013"
   }
 ]
```

O que faço para retornar o JSON desta maneira?

Comment: Porque precisa que retorne daquela maneira?

Comment: Exatamente por que necessita desse retorno? Não seria melhor criar essa variável do lado do cliente e atribuir o valor a ela?

Comment: `return this.Json(new { licencas = licencas }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` não? Ou `return this.Json(new { licencas = licencas.ToArray()}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: É estranho, já deve haver algo fora de padrão no teu código. Então uma tentativa seria retornar do jeito que o @MiguelAngelo demonstrou e fazer um pós processamento antes de utilizar, certifique-se que o JSON está em formato string e utilize um replace maroto de '"licencas":' para 'licencas = '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resposta da sua pergunta **"Como faço para retornar o JSON desta maneira?**

Simplesmente não faz. Você não pode retornar um JSON desta forma pois a sintaxe do JSON não permite, o formato mais adequado ao seu objeto com certeza é:

```json
{

    "licencas":[
        {
            "Responsavel":"José",
            "Ticket":79007,
            "Descricao":"RC - 01 Desktop padrão - José",
            "Status":"Pendente Gestão",
            "SLA":"10/10/2013"
        },
        {
            "Responsavel":"Maria",
            "Ticket":79037,
            "Descricao":"R‌​C - 01 Notebook padrão - Maria",
            "Status":"Pendente Pedido",
            "SLA":"10/11/2013"
        }
    ]

}
```

O código c# pra retornar este JSON é o informado pelo **@MiguelAngelo**:

```c#
return this.Json(new { licencas }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Você pode entender melhor o JSON utilizando [sites como este](http://json.parser.online.fr/) de uma olhada, no seu JSON por exemplo:

[image: json-parser-fr]

Posteriormente você poderá acessa-lo usando:

```c#
seuJSON.licensas[0].Responsavel; // José
seuJSON.licensas[0].Ticket;      // 79007
seuJSON.licensas[0].Descricao;   // RC - 01 Desktop padrão - José
seuJSON.licensas[0].Status;      // Pendente Gestão
seuJSON.licensas[0].SLA;         // 10/10/2013

seuJSON.licensas[1].Responsavel; // Maria
seuJSON.licensas[1].Ticket;      // 79037
seuJSON.licensas[1].Descricao;   // RC - 01 Notebook padrão - Maria
seuJSON.licensas[1].Status;      // Pendente Pedido
seuJSON.licensas[1].SLA;         // 10/11/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim para retornar o json que vai sair do jeito que você quer:

```
return this.Json(new { licencas }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Miguel, o códogo acima retorna:
{"licencas":[{"Responsavel":"José","Ticket":79007,"Descricao":"RC - 01 Desktop padrão - José","Status":"Pendente Gestão","SLA":"10/10/2013"},{"Responsavel":"Maria","Ticket":79037,"Descricao":"RC - 01 Notebook padrão - Maria","Status":"Pendente Pedido","SLA":"10/11/2013"}]}

com { iniciando e "licencas" como string e :

para dar certo precisa ser idêntico ao que postei

obrigado mesmo assim

Comment: Você deve saber que o valor exatamente da forma que quer, não é um JSON válido. Nenhum json inclui um sinal de igual.

Comment: Por isso que perguntei porque precisava ser daquela maneira, pois se você pegar o resultado JSON e atribuir a uma variável `licencas` vai ser o mais próximo da maneira que @Jhonatan quer...(Ex: `success: function(data) { var licencas = data; // ... o q quiser }` )

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar criar um novo `ActionResult`para fazer isso. Já fiz no passado um `JsonVariableResult` que fazia o que você queria, mas com a [webapi](/questions/tagged/webapi) e novidades no Framework acabei deletando o código.
Para não te frustrar, baixe o [ILSPY](http://ilspy.net/), e dê uma olhada no fonte das `ActionResults`, elas são muito simples, crie a sua e seja feliz!